# delete operation are extremely slow

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, file-system, operating-system

For some reason, moving files from my *Nexus 5X* to my PC takes **huge amounts of time**.

The copy "part" of the move operation is pretty much as fast as on any other Android device I've used (I can see the files actually being successfully created at the destination folder on my PC), but then, when the deletion "part" takes place (my indication is that all the files have been successfully copied and the progress bar reaches almost the end) -- the *Windows File Explorer* instance which handles the source folder just hangs, for a really long time.

For instance, when performing a move operation of 50 images, with an average size of 4MB each -- **the copy "part" takes a few seconds, while the deletion "part" takes more than 5 minutes**.

My question is: are there any specific tools, using which I can pinpoint the problem, or see a detailed log/real-time statistics regarding the deletion operation?

I'd appreciate any suggestions regarding the situation, which is obviously really problematic.

I've tried this on multiple laptops.

An important detail regarding my Android OS -- I have more than 29,000 images on my device (my entire *WhatsApp* history, since 2011). Maybe it has such impact on the file system?

I've attached a screenshot of the status bar and the "not responding" File Explorer window, during the deletion "part" of the move operation.
[image: Screenshot of the status bar and the "not responding" File Explorer window, during the deletion "part" of the move "operation".]

Comment: Have you tired to create some free space on the phone? I have observed similar things when device is  pretty full

Comment: Also on your laptop clearing recycle bin helps

Comment: @beeshyams currently I have 1GB of free space on my device. Anyway, it's a loop - I can't really make lots of free space, due to the fact that I can't move my camera photos to my PC.. It just takes too much time. Regarding your second comment - I've tried this on multiple laptops. The problem always recreates.

Comment: Interesting. Let's hope to have a definitive solution +1

Comment: First of all, what happens when you copy/move files inside phone with file manager without PC interaction? I had similar problem when my sd card went crazy and slowed down r/w speeds, so moving anything was pain in the ass. You can try app called "A1 SD benchmark" it should be able to test internal storage speeds so you can check is there anything unusuall. To me this sounds like hardware issue, and maybe just maybe android went crazy and factory reset will resolve a problem l, but I wouldn't recommend that due you can't backup your data.

Comment: @golosovsky Is this behavior experienced even when copying a single file from the phone to the computer?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman one of the questions I asked is here is a suggestion for a tool/utility to measure this type of things.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје thanks for the suggestion, I'll perform this test. BTW, it's an internal SD card.

Comment: Yeah I know that, I said similar case not the same. Maybe I'm not even close, but you should check.